# String not adding to List - Java

Tags: java

Im having an issue where im sending String variables to,from,subject,message and attachment to a server and when I go to place them in a list, the message variable is always null! I have outputted the variable message, and it comes up with what its supposed to but, but as soon as I put it in the list. its shows as null.

```
private void doSend(String name)
{
    String to = input.nextLine();
    String from = input.nextLine();
    String subject = input.nextLine();
    String message = input.nextLine();
    String attachment = input.nextLine();        

    System.out.println(to);
    System.out.println(from);
    System.out.println(subject);
    System.out.println(message);
    System.out.println(attachment);        

    // stores the message, but not into the mailbox        
    MultiEchoServer.MailBox.add(new Email(to, from,subject, message, attachment));

    System.out.println(MailBox);

    System.out.println("Message Sent to: " + to);
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Sample output

```
pj     // this is the to variable

dsds   // this is the from variable

subject  // this is the subject variable

message  // this is the message variable

[pj dsds subject null]  //this is the Mailbox List

Message Sent to: pj //not part of the error

message // this is the message variable being outputted again to see it it changed
```

I'm not even sure if anyone can help me, but let me know if you need to see more code thanks!

The Email Class

```
class Email
{
    private String to, from, subject,  message, attachment;
    int id;        

    public Email(String to ,String from ,String subject, String message, String attachment)
    {
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
        this.message = attachment;
    }

    public int id()
    {   
        return(id);
    }

    public String to()
    {
        return(to);
    }

    public String from()
    {   
        return(from);
    }

    public String subject()
    {
        return(subject);
    }

    public String message()
    {
        return(message);
    }
    public String attachment()
    {
        return(attachment);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return(to + " " + from + " " + subject + " " + message + "" + attachment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `toString()` method of `MailBox` class?

Comment: So, The problem is probably in the Email class, or maybe in the MailBox class. Show us their code. You should also learn to use a debugger and figure that out by yourself.

Comment: the Mailbox is a list of type Email

Comment: Perhaps not related to your question but `this.message = attachment;` should be `this.attachment= attachment;`

Comment: this.message = message;

this.message = attachment;

You're overriding message by attachment.

Comment: @AniketThakur: It's *absolutely* related to the question.

Comment: >Not related to your question but `this.message = attachment;`
Actually, that is related to the question, as it is likely setting message to `null`.

Comment: THANK YOU, its mad what you miss when you stare at a computer screen for ages

Comment: I see neither message or attachment to be null in the constructor. Assigning message twice should not make `message ` null. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The brackets in the return statements are very uncommon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem in your `Email` class `constructor`. Your assigning `message` field twice with `message` and `attachment`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on.  As @Dilip pointed out, there is an error in the constructor initializations.

Additionally, `attachment` is apparently an empty string.

Therefore, in the ctor, String field `message` is assigned an empty string and String field `attachment` is left uninitialized, and is therefore `null`.

In Java, `toString()` prints null values as the string literal "null".

"" is printed as the value of local variable `message` and "null" is printed as the value of local variable `attachment`.

This illustrates why using the same name for local variables, function parameters, and fields can be dangerous.

Additionally, using a String for something like an attachment, which may or may not be a String, depending on your implementation, is possibly a poor choice for this abstraction.